# <C-Up> does not work in Tmux + Vim configuration

Tags: vim, tmux

so, I have the following in .vimrc

```
nnoremap <C-Up> :bp<CR>
```

This works fine if I just use vim directly. But if I run vim within tmux then it does not work.

I don't have a tmux.conf file at all.

Comment: On macOS <C-Up> is eaten up by the OS to do something, I reckon the same is happening for you.

Answer (score 1):

~/.tmux.conf

```
set-option -gw xterm-keys on
bind-key -n C-Right send-keys C-Right
bind-key -n C-Up send-keys C-Up
bind-key -n C-Down send-keys C-Down
bind-key -n C-Left send-keys C-Left
```

~/.vimrc

```
set term=xterm
```

Verify that the value of

```
:set term?
```

in vim is same inside and outside of tmux session